# Why does string.split('\n') adds an extra element in the output list?

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list animals as below

```
animals = ['pets','dog\ncat\nchicken\ncow\n','wild','tiger\nlion\nrhino\n']
```

I want a separate list only for pets

```
pets = animals[1].split('\n')
```

print(pets) outputs ['dog', 'cat', 'chicken', 'cow', '']
The last element of the pets list i.e '' is undesirable

The line of code below removes the '' element from the list pets

```
pets = [i for i in animals[1].split('\n') if i]
```

Could you please explain why the former solution inserts '' in the list. Also, please clarify what is going on inside the list comprehension in the latter solution? what does "if i" represent?

Comment: because there is a newline character at the last. so splitting also occurs on the  last new line character and hence produce two parts as `cow` and empty string.

Comment: You can avoid it by using `animals[1].strip().split('\n')` or `animals[1].split()`

Comment: That's how it is supposed to be. Even php does the same.

Comment: Thanks @Alik for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Because always there is an empty string at the leading and trailing of a string (and between all the characters) :

```
>>> s='example'
>>> s.replace('','*')
'*e*x*a*m*p*l*e*'
```

And in this case you have a new line character at the trailing (actually before trailing empty string ) so after split you'll have a splitted empty string!

```
>>> s='dog\ncat\nchicken\ncow\n'
                               ^ #here is the empty string 
>>> s.split('\n')
['dog', 'cat', 'chicken', 'cow', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension iterates over every item in `animals[1].split('\n')` and then adds the item in a list if the value of `bool(i) == True` i.e. if i is not empty. This list comprehension is equivalent with:

```
pets = []
for i in animals[1].split('\n'):
    if i: # checks if i is not empty
        pets.append(i)
```